# IT startup: setting up environment for remote server and remote coding

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, remote-server, self-hosting, windows-hosting

#### I want to build an IT setup. At the very basic I want to setup few things

> - I want to have a central remote server which would have enough processing power to host everything. The local PCs should be on the economical end.
>
>   I want that all code and documents remain secure. None of my employees should be ableto take away with code or confidential documents.

The applications I would be working on would be mostly based on Java. I am thinking about the following setup. But I do am not sure about the feasibility or practicality of implementing it.

> 1. Buy a windows dedicated server from a hosting website. [Probably a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with around 16GB or 32 GB RAM]
>
>    Use economical windows desktops in the organization. [Probably Dual Core or Core I3 PCs.]
>
>    Host all code and applications/programs on the dedicated remote server.
>
>    Employees access the remote machine from their windows desktop using Remote Desktop (RDC). Do all coding and run applications on the remote machine only.
>
>    All internet access should be disabled on the remote server. So that there is no option to upload the code anywhere onto the internet.
>
>    Internet access should only be available on local machines.
>
>    Copy and Paste from the remote machine to the local machine should be restricted for all users other than administrator.
>
>    Copy and Paste from the local machine to the remote machine should be allowed.

Need suggestion if the above would work fine. I am actually in doubt about few things:

> 1. I have come to know that the RDC to remote server would require purchase and  installation of windows terminal services **TS** licenses, so that multiple  concurrent user login is possible. Is this correct?
>
>    If license cost could be deterrent for a startup would it be better to go for a  linux setup, where I can access desktop and programs using  SSH. I suppose the latter would not incur much costs as is in the case of buying  TS licenses.
>
>    Is it possible to setup such copy paste restrictions, which can only be managed  and changed by an administrator.
>
>    Do I need to setup VPN also? I think this might be needed so that the remote machine would only be accessible from my local office environment and not any other place.  I mean my employees or any other people should not be able to access the same remote machine from any other network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These is the typical setup of any large Software company. All these requirements are realistic. Get an experienced person/company to configure this environment. Any small mistakes in configuration might do a lot of damage to your Intellectual property.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sohan. I understand that the requirement matches that of a large software establishment. But mine is a start-up and I really can't invest huge amount. I would appreciate if there is some way through which I can I perform a DIY setup, with minimal costs.